# Nokogiri compare field and puts

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse a XML document and want to output a list of locations where the product name matches a string.

I'm able to output a list of all product names or a list of all locations but I'm not able to compare the two.  Removing the `if` portion of the statement correctly outputs all the locations.  What am I doing wrong with my regex?

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-EOXML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<product>
  <name>cool_fish</name>
  <product_details>
    <location>ocean</location>
    <costs>
      <msrp>9.99</msrp>
      <margin>5.00</margin>
    </costs>
  </product_details>
</product>
<product>
  <name>veggies</name>
  <product_details>
    <location>field</location>
    <costs>
      <msrp>2.99</msrp>
      <margin>1.00</margin>
    </costs>
  </product_details>
</product>    
</root>
EOXML

doc.xpath("//product").each do |x|
  puts x.xpath("location") if x.xpath("name") =~ /cool_fish/
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML <<-EOXML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<product>
  <name>cool_fish</name>
  <product_details>
    <location>ocean</location>
    <costs>
      <msrp>9.99</msrp>
      <margin>5.00</margin>
    </costs>
  </product_details>
</product>
<product>
  <name>veggies</name>
  <product_details>
    <location>field</location>
    <costs>
      <msrp>2.99</msrp>
      <margin>1.00</margin>
    </costs>
  </product_details>
</product>    
</root>
EOXML


@doc.xpath("//product").each do |x|
    puts x.at_xpath(".//location").text  if x.at_xpath(".//name").text =~ /cool_fish/
end
# >> ocean
```

You are parsing an `xml`, you should use [`Nokogiri::XML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML.html). Your [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) expression was also incorrect. You wrote `#xpath` method, but you were using expression, which you should use with methods like [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) or [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search). I used [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) method, as you were interested with the single node match inside the `#each` *block*.

But you can use [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) in place of `#at_xpath` and [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) in place of `xpath`.

Remember `search` and `at` both understand *CSS*, as well as *xpath* expressions. `search` or `xpath` or `css` all methods will give you [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), where as `at`, `at_css` or `at_xpath` would give you a [`Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html). Once a `Nokogiri` node will be in your hand, use [`text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text) method to get the content of that node.

Answer (score 2):

A few things going on here:

1. As others have pointed out, you should be parsing as XML not HTML, although that wouldn’t actually make much difference to the results you get.
2. You are parsing as a `DocumentFragment`, you should parse as a complete document. There are some issues involved querying document fragments, in particular queries starting with `//` don’t work right.
3. The `location` element is actually at the position `product_details/location` relative to  the `product` node in your XML, so you need to update your query to take that into account.
4. You are trying to use the `=~` operator on the result of the [`xpath` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) which is a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`. `NodeSet` doesn’t define a `=~` method, so it uses the [default one on `Object` that just returns `nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-7E), so it will never match. You should use `at_xpath` to only get the first result, and then call `text` on it to get the string that you can match using `=~`.

(Also you use `@doc` and `doc`, but I’m assuming that’s just a typo.)

So combining those four points your code will look like:

```
#parse using XML, and not a fragment
doc = Nokogiri::XML <<-EOXML
  # ... XML elided for space
EOXML

doc.xpath("//product").each do |x|
  # correct query, use at_xpath and call text method
  puts x.at_xpath("product_details/location") if x.at_xpath("name").text =~ /cool_fish/
end
```

However in this case you could do it all in a single XPath query, using the [`contains` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains):

```
# parse doc as XML document as above
puts doc.xpath("//product[contains(name, 'cool_fish')]/product_details/location")
```

This works because you have a fairly simple regex that only checks against a literal string.  XPath 1.0 doesn’t have support for regex, so if your real use case involves a more complex one you may need to do it the “hard way”. (You could write a custom XPath function in that case, but that’s another story.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Nokogiri::XML instead

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse <<-EOXML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<product>
  <name>cool_fish</name>
  <product_details>
    <location>ocean</location>
    <costs>
      <msrp>9.99</msrp>
      <margin>5.00</margin>
    </costs>
  </product_details>
</product>
<product>
  <name>veggies</name>
  <product_details>
    <location>field</location>
    <costs>
      <msrp>2.99</msrp>
      <margin>1.00</margin>
    </costs>
  </product_details>
</product>    
</root>
EOXML
```

and then the [Nokogiri::Node#search](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) and [Nokogiri::Node#at](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) methods

```
@doc.search("product").each do |x|
  puts x.at("location").content if x.at("name").content =~  /cool_fish/
end
```